# jQuery 3.5.1 using obsolete Mutation Events

Tags: jquery, content-security-policy

I'm testing CSP on my website and I have this warning :

*L’utilisation des « Mutation Events » est obsolète. Utiliser « MutationObserver » à la place. jquery.min.js:2:41540*

it seems the problem exist since jQuery 3.4.0 and is still alive on 3.5.1 according to this thread :
[https://forum.jquery.com/topic/warning-mutationobserver-responsive][1]
(I cannot login onto the forum.jquery.com website, there's a ZOHO problem)

Does someone has informations on this warning and is it possible to correct it ?
Thanks,
Vincent
[1]: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/warning-mutationobserver-responsive

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the exact version of jQuery you're using (assuming it's coming from a CDN). It would also be helpful to see the code which causes the error.

Comment: Hello, i'm using this one : https://owl.nolme.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As you can see in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/9aek0Lux/), it's not jQuery.js causing that error. Check the call stack when the error appears to find which line of your code is causing it, and debug from there.

Comment: how can I trace the call stack? I'm working with the root page owl.nolme.com under Firefox.

Comment: Open devtools and find the error in the console. Your browser should allow you to expand the error to see the stack trace of the calls that were made.

Comment: devtools seems to be available only on Chrome. So I installed Chrome. The message is slightly different :
"jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2 [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive"
But I'm still not able to see who is calling jquery on the landing page: https://owl.nolme.com :(

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the error from then, as this is the error list I see from your link: https://i.imgur.com/kvnxZTU.png. They are all coming from the mess of Facebook, chat and other tracking libraries you've added to the site.